# Azure: Unable to update test case results: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Getting below error while running a Maven pipeline with "Publish JUnit Tests with Attachments" task.

Background - by using Azure pipeline, uploading Test run attachments into Test cases.

The task consists "Test Case Mapping Type" as with below script

```
[
{
"className": "main.java.com.Tests.DMA_Smoke_SimpleLogin",
"methodName": "simpleLogin",
"testSuiteId": 5729,
"testCaseId": 5730
},
{
"className": "main.java.com.Tests.DMA_Regression_VerifyRequiredCode",
"methodName": "verifyRequiredCode",
"testSuiteId": 5729,
"testCaseId": 5731
}
]
```

Error Details -

```
Starting: Publish Results w Attch: 2702 Clone
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish JUnit Tests with Attachments (MetLife Cornerstone)
Description  : Publish test results with attachments tied to Azure Test Plan Test Cases
Version      : 1.4.2
Author       : MetLife Cornerstone
Help         : 
==============================================================================
Parsing JSON mapping: [
{
"className": "main.java.com.Tests.DMA_Smoke_SimpleLogin",
"methodName": "simpleLogin",
"testSuiteId": 5729,
"testCaseId": 5730,
"length":3534
},
{
"className": "main.java.com.Tests.DMA_Regression_VerifyRequiredCode",
"methodName": "verifyRequiredCode",
"testSuiteId": 5729,
"testCaseId": 5731,
"length":3535
}
]
Parsing JUnit Test Results file: D:\AzDOAgents\Agent1-MetLife-US-POC\_work\25\s\test-output\testng-results.xml
Creating test run entry.
200
Retrieved test run results
Unable to update test case results: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Completing testrun 1001010
200
{ id: 1001010,
  name: 'TestRun_QE framework mobile test_20221114.7',
  url: 'https://dev.azure.com/MetLife-US-POC/TechQA/_apis/test/Runs/1001010',
  build: { id: '2947' },
  isAutomated: true,
  owner: 
   { displayName: 'TechQA Build Service (MetLife-US-POC)',
     id: '81631c3a-706c-47af-bfee-a028667511b8' },
  project: { id: '8f053f76-b7f0-477f-9998-6a342ed0963d', name: 'TechQA' },
  startedDate: '2022-11-14T21:43:19.89Z',
  completedDate: '2022-11-14T21:43:20.603Z',
  state: 'Aborted',
  plan: { id: '5728' },
  totalTests: 2,
  incompleteTests: 0,
  notApplicableTests: 0,
  passedTests: 0,
  unanalyzedTests: 2,
  revision: 4,
  webAccessUrl: 'https://dev.azure.com/MetLife-US-POC/TechQA/_TestManagement/Runs?runId=1001010&_a=runCharts',
  pipelineReference: 
   { pipelineId: 2947,
     stageReference: {},
     phaseReference: {},
     jobReference: {} } }
Completed test run
##[error]Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Tried different ways to identify the issue. but still unable to get the solution.

Comment: Could  you provide your yaml pipeline ? It's not clear that what tasks in your yaml pipeline. And the "Test Case Mapping Type" seems like a json string not a script.

Comment: Thanks Dou Xu for your response. Currently, the task is internally developed by team. could we get any yaml script to update the test scripts, since I am new to Azure and Yaml

Comment: From your error detail, it seems like encountering an issue when reading `testng-results.xml` file. Can you provide the xml file sample for confirming the possible causes of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by consolidating xml files and passing the file to update the Test Cases.